# Getting unique result out of two lists of objects angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi I have two list of objects that i am trying to get unique objects in new list in my angular 4 component.

```
IList1 l1=[ {"_id":'a1', "name": "john"},
            _id":'a2', "name": "adam"},
             _id":'a3', "name": "jenny"}];

IList1 l2=[ {"_id":'a1', "name": "john"},
            _id":'b5', "name": "joe"},
             _id":'a3', "name": "jenny"}];
```

I am trying to write a code so that I can get the unique item in new list so

```
IList1 result=[_id":'b5', "name": "joe"}]
```

I am following is my code to get the result list

```
var len1=this.l1.length;
var len2=this.l2.lenth;
Ilist1 result=[];
for(var i=0; i<l1; i++)
   { 
     for(var y=0; y<l2; y++)
       {
         if(this.l1[i]._id !== this.l2[y]._id)
         this.result.push(this.l2[y])
       }
   }
```

Code above gives the result which is apposite of what I want basically it spits out the common objects in both lists. I tried to change !== to == still not giving the expected result.
Please let me know how I can fix it to get unique record into the result list. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what is happening with your current code:

This is what your code is doing in english:

1. For each element of list l1 (`for(var i=0; i<l1; i++)`);
2. go through list l2 (`for(var y=0; y<l2; y++)`);
3. if the element of l1 is not on all elements of l2 (`if(this.l1[i]._id !== this.l2[y]._id)`)
4. add it to the list (`this.result.push(this.l2[y])`)

So what's wrong there is step 3, which translated into execution we get on the first iteration of the part for loop:

```
l1[0] !== l2[0] ("a2" !== "a1") // true- result = []
l1[0] !== l2[1] ("a2" !== "b5") // true - result = [{"_id":'b5', "name": "joe"}]
l1[0] !== l2[2] ("a2" !== "a3") // true - result = [{"_id":'b5', "name": "joe"}, {"_id":'a3', "name": "jenny"}]
```

On the second iteration:

```
l1[1] !== l2[0] ("a1" !== "a1") // false - result = [{"_id":'b5', "name": "joe"}, {"_id":'a3', "name": "jenny"}, {"_id":'a1', "name": "john"}]
l1[1] !== l2[1] ("a1" !== "b5") // true - result = [{"_id":'b5', "name": "joe"}, {"_id":'a3', "name": "jenny"}, {"_id":'a1', "name": "john"},{"_id":'b5', "name": "joe"}]
l1[1] !== l2[2] ("a1" !== "a3") // true - result = [{"_id":'b5', "name": "joe"}, {"_id":'a3', "name": "jenny"}, {"_id":'a1', "name": "john"},{"_id":'b5', "name": "joe"},{"_id":'b5', "name": "joe"}]
```

So you can see that your condition is not ok because all other elements that are not equal to the current element under test is going to be added to your list.

So to make the logic simpler let's just concat the 2 arrays and apply the same logic as before only going through the same concatenated list twice and using a boolean that tells you if the element is a duplicate or not:

```js
var l1 = [{
    "_id": 'a1',
    "name": "john"
  },
  {
    "_id": 'a2',
    "name": "adam"
  },
  {
    "_id": 'a3',
    "name": "jenny"
  }
];

var l2 = [{
    "_id": 'a1',
    "name": "john"
  },
  {
    "_id": 'b5',
    "name": "joe"
  },
  {
    "_id": 'a3',
    "name": "jenny"
  }
];
var result = [];
var joinedArray = l1.concat(l2);
for (var i = 0; i < joinedArray.length; i++) {
  var isDuplicate = false;
  for (var y = 0; y < joinedArray.length; y++) {
    if (i != y && this.joinedArray[i]._id === this.joinedArray[y]._id)
      isDuplicate = true;
  }
  if (!isDuplicate)
    this.result.push(joinedArray[i]);
}

console.log(result)
```

This solution is not the most efficient or the most logic, but it should be easier to understand since it's closer to your original logic.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably count the objects in a hash keyed to the id. Then `filter()` & `map()` that count object for items with a count of 1.

```js
let l1=[ {"_id":'a1', "name": "john"},{"_id":'a2', "name": "adam"},{"_id":'a3', "name": "jenny"}];
let l2=[ {"_id":'a1', "name": "john"},{"_id":'b5', "name": "joe"},{"_id":'a3', "name": "jenny"}];

// make an object that counts the items
// only need to store the last item since you're looking for uniques
let counts = [...l1, ...l2].reduce((obj, item) =>{
    if (obj[item._id]) obj[item._id].count++
    else obj[item._id] = {count:1, object: item}
    return obj
}, {})

// filter that object by count and return the objects
let filtered = Object.values(counts).filter(item => item.count === 1).map(item => item.object)
console.log(filtered)
```